# Squid confiuration with LDAP on Centos 7

Tags: authentication, ldap, squid

I installed squid on Centos 7 for LDAP authentication, but the problem is that the */usr/lib64/squid* directory does not contain the *squid_ldap_auth* file when I installed: squid, openldap, openldap-clients, and nss_ldap.
On my old server the file *squid_ldap_auth* is present in the */usr/lib64/ squid* directory.
Can anyone help me set up squid for LDAP authentication, on Centos 6/7 or Debian 7/8?
thank you in advance

Tony92

Answer (score 0):

The directory where the helpers go is defined during the build process (if you are building from source). Usually the default is /usr/lib/squid. If the helper is not there, then the package you have used to install squid was not build with the option to include ldap. If you are building squid from source, when you run `.configure` you need to specify option `--enable-auth-basic=LDAP` (this option is for squid 3.5 I think the older versions have slightly different syntax). Also if you use this option you need to have openldap libraries installed on your centOS machine for the build to succeed.

Answer (score 0):

Answering this very old question because I was looking for the same info. If anyone else is looking for the same, the module is available as `/usr/lib64/squid/basic_ldap_auth`. Info on how to configure it are more or less the same as the `squid_ldap_auth` (see [man page](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/squid/basic_ldap_auth.8.en.html)):

Config example (for RedHat, but it should be the same on other distr) is on [RedHat docs](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/networking_guide/setting-up-squid-as-a-caching-proxy-with-ldap-authentication).
Note: I've removed `-ZZ` as it was preventing this from working as I don't use SSL over LDAP, here's an example for `/etc/squid/squid.conf`:

```
auth_param basic program /usr/lib64/squid/basic_ldap_auth -b "cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=example,dc=com" -D "uid=proxy_user,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=example,dc=com" -W /etc/squid/ldap_password -f "(&(objectClass=person)(uid=%s))" -H ldap://ldap_server.example.com:389
```

To test it you can directly run the module:

```
# /usr/lib64/squid/basic_ldap_auth -b "cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=example,dc=com" -D "uid=proxy_user,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=example,dc=com" -W /etc/squid/ldap_password -f "(&(objectClass=person)(uid=%s))" -H ldap://ldap_server.example.com:389
```

If you're using IPA you can search the info to use with

```
ldapsearch -Y GSSAPI '(&(objectClass=person)(uid=myuser))' dn
```